# Removing rows that have slashes in a specific column

Tags: r, string-matching, data-wrangling

In a data frame, I have some strings in a column that have /// in it. Is there a way for me to search for strings that have that /// pattern and remove that row completely?

I have this DF1:

| Name | Key | group1 | group2 | group3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XAS /// HUA | test1234 | 10 | 10 | 8 |
| MPA1 /// AAS2 | test4553 | 8 | 7 | 4 |
| MPAS | test3341 | 5 | 5 | 5 |
| SSPA1 | test2142 | 5 | 6 | 8 |
| MAS61A | test4722 | 6 | 7 | 4 |

Essentially, this dataframe is very large, and so I want to keyword search in the first column for that pattern, and if it is present, to drop that row. To get this as the result below. Whats the best way to do so? Thanks!

| Name | Key | group1 | group2 | group3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MPAS | test3341 | 5 | 5 | 5 |
| SSPA1 | test2142 | 5 | 6 | 8 |
| MAS61A | test4722 | 6 | 7 | 4 |

```
# DF1
Name <- c("XAS /// HUA", "MPA1 /// AAS2", "MPAS", "SSPA1", "MAS61A")
Key <- c("test1234", "test4553", "test3341", "test2142", "test4722")
group1 <- c(10, 8, 5, 5, 6)
group2 <- c(10, 7, 5, 6, 7)
group3 <- c(8, 4, 5, 8, 4)
DF1 <- data.frame(Name, Key, group1, group2, group3)
```

Comment: You've already got good answers, but just on the off chance that it is literally 3 "/" then you would need to specify the number of forward slashes ie. `!str_detect(Name, "/{3}")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using negated `grepl`.

```
DF1[!grepl('/', DF1$Name), ]
#     Name      Key group1 group2 group3
# 3   MPAS test3341      5      5      5
# 4  SSPA1 test2142      5      6      8
# 5 MAS61A test4722      6      7      4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `str_detect` with the operator `!`.

#### Code

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

DF1 %>% 
  filter(!str_detect(Name,"//"))
```

#### Output

```
    Name      Key group1 group2 group3
1   MPAS test3341      5      5      5
2  SSPA1 test2142      5      6      8
3 MAS61A test4722      6      7      4
```